# Task<ObservableCollection<AppointmentItem>> does not contain definition for where

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, task, observablecollection

I am attempting to filter an observablecollection by the date saved inside. The user will select the date by using a calender view.

```
public async Task RefreshItems(bool showActivityIndicator, bool syncItems)
        {
            using (var scope = new ActivityIndicatorScope(syncIndicator, showActivityIndicator))
            {

                var items = manager.GetAppointmentItemsAsync();


                CalendarVM vm = new CalendarVM();
                calendar.SetBinding(Calendar.DateCommandProperty, nameof(vm.DateChosen));
                calendar.SetBinding(Calendar.SelectedDateProperty, nameof(vm.DateSelected));
                calendar.BindingContext = vm;

                var filtered = items.Where(appointmentItem => appointmentItem.Date == SelectedDate);
            }
        }
```

Here is the code from the AppointmentPage class with the user selected date and the data.

```
  public async Task<ObservableCollection<AppointmentItem>> GetAppointmentItemsAsync(bool syncItems = false)
        {


            try
            {

                IEnumerable<AppointmentItem> items = await appointmentTable
                                        .ToEnumerableAsync();

                return new ObservableCollection<AppointmentItem>(items);

            }
            catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"Invalid sync operation: {0}", msioe.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"Sync error: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            return null;

        }
```

and here is the code from the dataManger class to retrieve the data from the database.

Currently I am getting this error:

> Error CS1061  'Task>' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'Task>' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 3):

Your following line of code:

```
var items = manager.GetAppointmentItemsAsync();
```

returns a `Task` which obviously doesn't contain `Where` and that's why you're getting an error.

Please change this line to:

```
var items = await manager.GetAppointmentItemsAsync();
```

and then you will get back a collection of type `ObservableCollection<AppointmentItem>` which should have `Where` member.

Comment: `<blush />` :) #WishStackOverflowAllowedSmallerComments. BTW, give some love to @Alessandro Caliaro as well :D. He was 1st one to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

I try to change

```
var items = manager.GetAppointmentItemsAsync();
```

to

```
ObservableCollection<AppointmentItem> items = await manager.GetAppointmentItemsAsync();
```

then you can try to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: @glenncooper Damn it! I have answered so many questions on SO and no one has told me they love me... Feeling jealous